# Simulate and control multiple AR drones in tum_simulator+Gazebo+ROS

Tags: ros, tum-simulator, ros-kinetic, ardrone2.0

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

**Update**: I have also installed hector packages mentioned in [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/281462/drone-keeps-rising-in-simulation-after-takeoff/?answer=281463#post-id-281463) post. It was need to control a single drone.

I am currently trying to simulate (and potentially wish to control) two Parrot A.R. drones in [tum_simulator](http://wiki.ros.org/tum_simulator) + Gazebo 7 + ROS Kinetic setup.

- I am having the exact same issue as asked [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/62981/multiple-ardrones-on-tum_simulator/). **The first drone keeps rising** when the command to takeoff is published.
- I have also used code from [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/41433/multiple-robots-simulation-and-navigation/) but it doesnt improve anything for me.
- I also came across this [github pull request](https://github.com/dougvk/tum_simulator/pull/9) for tum_simulator for ROS indigo. However, it doesn't seem to have been merged in with the master branch which leads me to think whether it is correct modification or not? (Also, I'm currently using kinetic while the pull request is for indigo. I don't mind reinstalling indigo, but I don't know if that code is correct or not).

**Anyone who has faced this issue** before and managed to find a solution,
Could you kindly help me out ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282510/simulate-and-control-multiple-ar-drones-in-tum_simulator+gazebo+ros/) by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2018-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try installing some [hector packages described here](https://answers.ros.org/question/281462/drone-keeps-rising-in-simulation-after-takeoff/?answer=281463#post-id-281463)

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-02-13**:
Hi, I have already done that earlier. It was required to control a single drone.